# how to use __name__ attribute to get respective outputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`__name__` is the special attribute in python and has the value of module name.

Values of `__name__` of try2.py, try1.py, try3.py are 'try2', 'try1' and 'try3' respectively.

What shall I replace in if condition in try2.py to get respective outputs in files try1.py and try3.py respectively?

## file: try2.py

```
class A(object):
    a=[]    
def add(self,p,q):
    return p+q
def minus(self,p,q):
    return p-q

#I know that if i replace 'try1' by 'try2' in if condition,
#then this can be executed where try2.py will be imported
if(__name__=='try1'):
    print('runs only if module name is try1')
elif(__name__=='try3'):
    print('runs only if module name is try3')
```

## file: try1.py

```
import try2

print(try2.A().add(2,3))
```

## file: try3.py

```
import try2
print(try2.A().minus(2,3))
```

Comment: ... What? `__name__` in try2.py will be "try2" if you import it.

Comment: yes i want to print different line in try1.py and try3.py respectively

Comment: @VibhorVerma,  your comment does not help to clear anything up. Also where is try3?

Comment: But *you're not in* try1.py or try3.py. You're in try2.py.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes, i am not try1 or try3, but i want try2 when imported in try1 and try3 to print different output, is this possible?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham edited the ques, added try3.py file

Comment: What are you *actually trying to achieve*? Why do you think this is a good implementation to work towards?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am trying to print different lines in different files i.e. try1.py and try3.py in which try2.py is imported. I don't know if it is good implementation, i am just trying to get desired output

Comment: But *why*? That doesn't really give any context.

Comment: @jonrsharpe bro if you can solve the problem, then solve it, else don't ask inappropriate question 'why'. consider this a problem and desired output be different for different files.

Comment: "Why" is rarely an inappropriate question. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731. If you're solving the wrong problem you're wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @jonrsharpe nice read, thanks :-) , actually there is no X, i am just figuring out if Y can work(being enthuthiastic)? thats it

Answer (score 3):

There's only two things `__name__` can ever be.

If you run a module directly, its `__name__` will be `"__main__"`.

Otherwise, you must have imported it; its `__name__` will be the name of the module. It's not possible for the name of try2 to ever be "try1" or "try3".

Comment: what can be replace this above code to get the desired output?

Comment: I know this, that you are saying

Comment: Well, technically, if you hard-linked `try2.py` as `try3.py`... No, this is not a reasonable counter to your general point, and anyone who does something like this should be shot, but still. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger I am not asking if someone be shot dead, i want to ask if something i can replace in if conditions in try2.py  to get different output in different files in which it is imported :-)